# Converting LV to thin pool: VG name mismatch

Tags: linux, lvm, docker, thinpool

I'm trying to create a thin pool for docker as i'm changing the root location of docker and i had to delete previous thin pool. 
Info about situation:

```
vgs
  VG  #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  cah   1   3   0 wz--n- 118.75g <41.53g

lvs
  LV        VG  Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root      cah -wi-ao----   3.00g
  swap      cah -wi-ao---- <11.93g
  workspace cah -wi-ao---- <62.30g
```

Then I run the following commands to create LVs for thinpool:

```
[root@dockxx04 docker]# lvcreate --wipesignatures y -n docker-pool cah -l 99%FREE
  Logical volume "docker-pool" created.


[root@dockxx04 docker]# lvcreate --wipesignatures y -n docker-poolmeta cah -l 27%FREE
  Logical volume "docker-poolmeta" created.
```

And now i need to convert these LVs into thin pool. And this is what happens:

```
[root@dockxx04 docker]# lvconvert -y --zero n -c 512K --thinpool /dev/cah/docker-pool --poolmetadata /dev/cah/docker-poolmeta
  VG name mismatch from position arg (cah) and option arg ().
```

This is 5th machine that i'm reconfiguring and the other went without a problem and are working fine now. 
What is wrong here? What it actually means and how to resolve this?

Comment: how did you come up with the %FREE numbers? just curious... also it's a bit odd to use `lvconvert`, why not `lvcreate` thin pool in the first place? (unless the lvcreate was just setting up the test case)

Comment: An idea. Could you try the command without the `/dev/` prefixes, like so:
`lvconvert -y --zero n -c 512K --thinpool cah/docker-pool --poolmetadata cah/docker-poolmeta`

Comment: @Frostschutz thanks for the tip, it actually worked well. I don't know why the docker documentation made me do it by converting 2 logical volumes into thin pool.

Comment: @Edward I thought the same, tried that. It didn't work.